# How can I get the DbContext from a POCO's Proxy in EF 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

How can I get the DbContext from a POCO's Proxy in EF 4.1 ?

I can see the ObjectContext in the debugger, but can't find the DbContext.

Comment: You should never need this. If you need this you should think about refactoring your code.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav. That convinces me not to rely on this approach. Currently I am just messing with some extension methods and don't have a very strict performance need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DbContext` has this overloaded constructor:

```
public DbContext(ObjectContext objectContext, bool dbContextOwnsObjectContext)
```

So, you could try this to create a `DbContext` wrapping the `objectContext` which you retrieved from your proxy: Create an appropriate constructor for your derived context...

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(ObjectContext objectContext,bool dbContextOwnsObjectContext)
        : base(objectContext, dbContextOwnsObjectContext)
    {
    }
}
```

...and then call it this way:

```
var myContext = new MyContext(objectContext, false);
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, when I tried using "Tip 24" from msdn blogs to get the `ObjectContext` I could not get the `SourceQuery` for the entity because it was in the Added state. I guess there is no simple way. Could I get the derived context with reflection somehow?

Comment: @Benjamin. I have no clue. The caveats in that Tip 24 don't sound nice, especially about performance, and it won't become better with reflection (if there is a way at all).

Comment: Thanks for your help Slauma. It seems to work great if the entities are not added or detached.